# How to do server-side sorting with Datatables.AspNet.Mvc5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, datatables

I'm attempting to do server-side processing of jQuery DataTables using ASP.NET MVC with Entity Framework. I came across [Datatables.AspNet](https://github.com/ALMMa/datatables.aspnet) Nuget package, but I'm unclear how to use it to dynamically sort columns when clicked on table headers.

In an [example on Datatables.AspNet GitHub](https://github.com/ALMMa/datatables.aspnet/blob/master/samples/DataTables.AspNet.Samples.Mvc5.BasicIntegration/Controllers/HomeController.cs), there is this:

```
public ActionResult PageData(IDataTablesRequest request)
{
    var data = Models.SampleEntity.GetSampleData(); 
    var filteredData = data.Where(_item => _item.Name.Contains(request.Search.Value));

    // Paging filtered data.
    var dataPage = filteredData.Skip(request.Start).Take(request.Length);

    var response = DataTablesResponse.Create(request, data.Count(), filteredData.Count(), dataPage);

    return new DataTablesJsonResult(response, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

But I'm unsure how to proceed to dynamically sort based on the contents of the IDataTablesRequest object, which looks like this:

```
public interface IDataTablesRequest
{
    int Draw { get; }
    int Start { get; }        
    int Length { get; }
    ISearch Search { get; }
    IEnumerable<IColumn> Columns { get; }
    IDictionary<string, object> AdditionalParameters { get; }
}

public interface ISort
{
    int Order { get; }
    SortDirection Direction { get; }
}

public enum SortDirection
{
    Ascending = 0,
    Descending = 1
}
```

Comment: have a look here : https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1118363/GridView-with-Server-Side-Filtering-Sorting-and-Pa

Comment: @EhsanSajjad, thanks, but it looks like your code is based on an older version of Datatables.AspNet package.  `GetSortedColumns` method doesn't seem to exist any more.

Comment: Actually, just realized that I'm using a different Nuget package. Yours is referencing `datatables.mvc5` and I'm using `datatables.aspnet.mvc5` which seem like two unrelated projects, which would explain the "missing" method. But I still get the idea. Will look closer at your code to see if I can apply it.

Answer (score 5):

take a look at this answer: https://github.com/ALMMa/datatables.aspnet/issues/26

for reference:

```
public static IQueryable<T> OrderBy<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, IEnumerable<DataTables.AspNet.Core.IColumn> sortModels)
        {
            var expression = source.Expression;
            int count = 0;
            foreach (var item in sortModels)
            {
                var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "x");
                var selector = Expression.PropertyOrField(parameter, item.Field);
                var method = item.Sort.Direction == DataTables.AspNet.Core.SortDirection.Descending ?
                    (count == 0 ? "OrderByDescending" : "ThenByDescending") :
                    (count == 0 ? "OrderBy" : "ThenBy");
                expression = Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), method,
                    new Type[] { source.ElementType, selector.Type },
                    expression, Expression.Quote(Expression.Lambda(selector, parameter)));
                count++;
            }
            return count > 0 ? source.Provider.CreateQuery<T>(expression) : source;
        }
```

so you can do the following:

```
var orderColums = request.Columns.Where(x => x.Sort != null);
 var dataPage = data.OrderBy(orderColums).Skip(request.Start).Take(request.Length);
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is late answer but for anyone interested.... using Datatable on Asp .NET Core

here YOURMODEL: should be the same type

```
public IEnumerable<YOURMODEL> SortDataByColumn(IEnumerable<YOURMODEL> data, IDataTablesRequest request){

     var sortColumn = request.Columns.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Sort != null);

     if(sortColumn == null) return data;

     if (sortColumn.Sort.Direction == SortDirection.Descending)
     {
        return data.OrderByDescending(c => c.GetType().GetProperty(sortColumn.Field).GetValue(c));
     }

    return data.OrderBy(c => c.GetType().GetProperty(sortColumn.Field).GetValue(c));
}
```

FYI..This assumes a sort on a single column.....

Answer (score 0):

// c#

public class JQueryDataTableParamModel
{
public Int32 start { get; set; }

```
    public Int32 length { get; set; }

    public JQueryDataTableOrder[] order { get; set; }

   public class JQueryDataTableOrder
    {
        public Int32 column { get; set; }

        public String dir { get; set; }
    }
```

}

MyFunctionName: function (tableId)

```
{

                    $(tableId).DataTable({
                    serverSide: true,
                    processing: true,
                    deferRender: true,
                    "bPaginate": true,
                    "bLengthChange": false,
                    "bFilter": false,
                    "bInfo": true,
                    "bAutoWidth": true,
                    "ordering": true,
                    "bSortClasses": false,
                    "bDestroy": true,
                    bLengthChange: false,
                    "iDisplayLength": 50,
                    responsive: true,
                    dom: 'Bfrtip',
     ajax: function (data, callback, s) {
      var parms = {
      start: data.start,
     length: data.length,
   order[{column:data.order[0].column,dir:data.order[0].dir}],
     addtionalParam: $('#IdOfTheTextBox').val(),
      }

                        ajax =
                            $.ajax({
                                url: '/AreaName/ControllerName/Method',
                                type: "POST",
                                contentType: "application/json",
                                dataType: 'json',
                                data: JSON.stringify(parms),
                                success: function (data) { callback(data); },
                                error: function (e) {
                                  // can add sweetalert or normal alert
                                }
                            });
                    },
                    aoColumns: [
                        {
                            sName: "Name",
                            render: function (a, b, c) {
                                return '<td>' + a + '</td>'
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            sName: "Surname",
                            render: function (a, b, c) { return '<td>' + a + '</td>' }
                        },                  
                        {
                            sName: "Id",
                            "bSortable": false,
                            sClass: "action",
                            render: function (a, b, c) {
                             return "This will be your button(s)"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                });
```

}

public JsonResult MethodSignature(string additionalParam, JQueryDataTableParamModel param)
{

```
      var myList= GetYourList();

       if (param.order[0].dir == "asc")
          myList= myList.OrderBy(x=>x.Name);
       else
          myList= myList.OrderByDescending(x=>x.Name);

       var dataToReturn= sm.Skip(param.start).Take(param.length).ToList().Select(x
        => new object[]
       {
           x.Name,
           x.Surname,
           x.Id
       });

       return Json(new
       {
           iTotalRecords = myList.Count(),
           iTotalDisplayRecords = myList.Count(),
           <a href="//legacy.datatables.net/ref#aaData">aaData</a> = dataToReturn,
       }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
   }
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Thanks for answering but can you also add an explanation on how your code solves the issue? Check the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for info on how to format code.